# How make nested http query in AngularJs?

Tags: ajax, facebook, http, angularjs

Iam build single page app in AngularJs,and I need call Facebook UI dialog.And if user click 'ok',or 'cancel',successReport methos not call immediately.This method call after i click on any button in page,or link.Similar to internal queue

```
 service.showStreamDialog=function (json) {
    if (json.stream) {
        var newCardSentId = json.cardSentId;
        FB.ui(json.stream, function (resp) {
            if (resp && resp.post_id) {
                reportService.successReport(newCardSentId,newCardSentId,resp.post_id);
            } else {
                reportService.cancelReport(newCardSentId);
            }

        });
    }
};
```

// in other file

```
var successReport=function(cardId,cardSentId,postId){
    var defered = $q.defer();
    $http.post(reportUrl,$.param({
        cardId:cardId,
        cardSentId:cardSentId,
        postId:postId,
        accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN
    }))
    .success(function(data){
        defered.resolve(data);})
    .error(function(data){
       defered.reject(data);
    });

    return defered.promise;

};
```

**I found problem**. It was in integration facebook api in my app.I add $rootScope.$apply call,
and all working as i expected

```
service.showStreamDialog = function (json) {
        if (json.stream) {
            var newCardSentId = json.cardSentId;
            FB.ui(json.stream, function (resp) {
                if (resp && resp.post_id) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('CARD_SENT_SUCCESS', {cardSentId: newCardSentId,post_id:resp.post_id});
                    });
                } else {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('CARD_SENT_CANCEL', {cardSentId: newCardSentId});
                    });
                }

            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: question is not clear...please add more specifics

Comment: I want that the call successReport  immediately after FB.ui received response from facebook.But now it occurs after any user action

Comment: couldn't you set a flag in your service and store the response data there.... then elsewhere in app call `reportService.successReport` ? Hard to know how you want other user actions to trigger queued post